# How to retrieve a big amount of tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I´m trying to retrieve a big amount of tweets, like 1000 or 3000 per minute, now I´m using the public API of twitter with the URL:

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#whatever+OR+@whatever&since=15-05-2015&count=100&result_type=recent

but the problem is that I need more than 100 tweets because Twitter only supports 180 request every 15 mins, and always I need more than than, my question is that if there is somewhere a twitter API that can do what the public API but can retrieve more than 100 tweets per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort answer is that there is no legitimate way to get around the rate limits of the Rest API.

You can request "whitelisting" for your application, but Twitter doesn't do it very often and not for average users.

The Streaming API might provide the specific functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: I will see this solution, sounds very good to me, thanks! more info in https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview